# concatenate images with jquery

Tags: jquery, image

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    img$ = '';
    var img$ = img$ + '<img src = ' + $('#img_loc').attr('value') + ' />'; 

            /*#img_loc is the id of the text box where url is pasted*/

    $('#add_btn').click(function() {
        $('#work_area').html(img$);
    });
});
```

I want to be able to place image after image by pasting different URLs into the `img_loc` text box. But with this code, I can only ever get one image to show up. Can someone please help me see what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than replacing the work_area each time, why not append images to it as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#add_btn').click(function() { 
        var src = $('#img_loc').val();
        $('<img>').attr("src", src).appendTo($('#work_area'));
    }); 
});
```

Comment: @Phil_Klein--If i do this, the img is appended to the outside the work_area div. I need the images to be displayed inside it. Any idea how i could do this?

Comment: I updated the answer to clean things up.  Click here to see a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/HHr5C/3/

Comment: @Phil_Klein--nvm it does work. I'm a bit confused though... i thought `.append` and `.appendTo` attached content to the outside of the wrapped elements. Why isnt that the case here?

Comment: You're thinking of `.after()` I believe.